# FTP to Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, ftp, google-cloud-storage

I need to write ftp script to move the file from File location to google cloud.

I could do this manually using CrossFTP. where it does have component to connect to Google cloud using Access key and secret key. but when i use FTP script i am not able to connect it.

If I want to use traditional FTP way for google cloud what should be server name and user ID and pass. I tried using commondatastorage.googleapis.com But it does work with access key and secret key.

Any information will be helpful.

All I need is, I need to automate this FTP process.

Comment: Which OS do you use ? And which language ?

Comment: FTP is not enabled. Are you trying to upload files in to the Cloud Storage? If so use the gsutil https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: FTP is very outdated. Why do you think Google supports it? Unless you have a GCE machine where you install it yourself I don't think there's any other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're automating using a shell script, you can use [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil).  This allows you to upload / download files, modify ACLs and so on.